# How to create if statement for two dropdown cases

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown

I am trying to get my if statement to output a different url based on two dropdown menus. The if statement/function should read both dropdowns and then based on them if should make identify a url. I have created all of the urls but I cannot get the code to work.

```
   <form action="/action_page.php">
 <select id="Group">
<option value="Choose Group">Choose Group</option>
<option value="Senior Soldiers">Senior Soldiers</option>
<option value="Jr Soldiers">Jr Soldiers</option>
<option value="Corps Cadets">Corps Cadets</option>
<option value="VBS">VBS</option>
<option value="Learning Zone">Learning Zone</option>
<option value="Men's Ministry">Men's Minstry</option>
<option value="Women's Ministry">Women's Ministry</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</form>  
<form action="/action_page.php">
<select id="Location Select">
<option value="Choose Location">Choose Location</option>
<option value="Akron">Akron</option>
<option value="Alliance">Alliance</option>
<option value="Ashland">Ashland</option>
<option value="Barberton">Barberton</option>
<option value="Ballaire">Bellaire</option>
<option value="Cambridge">Cambridge</option>
<option value="Camp NEOSA">Camp NEOSA</option>
<option value="Canton">Canton</option>
<option value="Cleveland East Cleveland">Cleveland East 
Cleveland</option>
<option value="Cleveland Miles Park">Cleveland Miles Park</option>
<option value="Cleveland New Hope">Cleveland New Hope</option>
<option value="Cleveland Ohio City">Cleveland Ohio City</option>
<option value="Cleveland Temple">Cleveland Temple</option>
<option value="Cleveland West Park">Cleveland West Park</option>
<option value="Coshocton">Coshocton</option>
<option value="DHQ">DHQ</option>
<option value="Dover">Dover</option>
<option value="East Liverpool">East Liverpool</option>
<option value="Elyria">Elyria</option>
<option value="Lorain">Lorain</option>
<option value="Mansfield">Mansfield</option>
<option value="Massillon">Massillon</option>
<option value="Medina">Medina</option>
<option value="Mount Vernon">Mount Vernon</option>
<option value="Newark">Newark</option>
<option value="Norwalk">Norwalk</option>
<option value="Painesville">Painesville</option>
<option value="Ravenna">Ravenna</option>
<option value="Salem">Salem</option>
<option value="Sandusky">Sandusky</option>
<option value="Steubenville">Steubenville</option>
<option value="Toledo">Toledo</option>
<option value="Wadsworth">Wadsworth</option>
<option value="Warren">Warren</option>
<option value="Wooster">Wooster</option>
<option value="Youngstown Citadel">Youngstown Citadel</option>
<option value="Youngstown Temple">Youngstown Temple</option>
<option value="Zanesville">Zanesville</option>
</select>
</form>
<script> if (Group = 'Jr Soldiers' && Location Select = 'Akron') {
getURL()
}
</script>

var getURL = function(){
var option1 = document.getElementById('Group').value;
var option2 = document.getElementById('Location').value;
var URL = 'http:www.campneosa.org'
```

}
    Run

Comment: You’ve got a few problems with your code. Either you’ve only copied half of it, or there is a problem. For example you open two `<form>`s, but don”t close them. Separate each part out, or show us the complete forms.

Comment: can't you just make like this after getting the values: `if (option1 == 'Akron' && option2 == 'Senior Soldiers'){ do code }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a scope issue with the script. Your script won't be able to determine what `Group` or `Location Select` mean and you will encounter an error. Before you reference these, you will need to assign them as a variable like you have implemented in the bottom section of your code like so:

```
var option1 = document.getElementById('Group').value;
var option2 = document.getElementById('Location').value;
```

You're on the right track with the function though, so try and lay it out like this

```
if (option1 == "Akron" && option2 == "Senior Soldiers") {
   url = "www.example.com";

   alert(url);
}
```

(Rinse and repeat this part with `else if` conditions until you lay out your desired options)